# How to add text in the beginning of each record in a row in sql

Tags: sql

i have the following data set in the leads column:

```
**leads**
1234567
1234534
1234543
```

i want it to be updated as

```
**leads**
LEA-1234567
LEA-1234534
LEA-1234543
```

Comment: Seems like an odd idea. Why?

Comment: create a view as `SELECT CONCAT('LEA-', leads) AS leads`

Comment: Just as result of a query, or actually / permanently in the database table??

Comment: What rdbms are you working with? different products use different operators. For example, Oracle use `||` while Sql Server use `+` for string concatenation.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to use update script directly

```
update table set table.leads = concat('LEA-', table.leads)
```

Comment: What happens if the `Leads` column is of datatype `int` ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat`.

```
select
  concat('LEA-', leads) as lead
from yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET leads = "LEA-" || leads
```

Answer (score -1):

Update  tablename
set leads='LEA-'+leads